# How can I split the array in JavaScript preserving the unique values of the keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

From the below array how can I ensure I fetch the rows uniquely with same key values.
For KFC I want two rows to appear. However for the code I have I can get only the latest.

```
ratingData = [
{restaurant: 'KFC', rating:5},
{restaurant: 'Burger King', rating:4},
{restaurant: 'KFC', rating:3},
{restaurant: 'Domino', rating:2},
{restaurant: 'Subway', rating:3},
{restaurant: 'Domino', rating:1},
{restaurant: 'Subway', rating:4},
{restaurant: 'Pizza Hut', rating:5}
]

console.log(Object.keys(ratingData));

rest = ratingData.map(({restaurant}) => restaurant);
console.log(rest);
console.log(ratingData.map(({rating}) => rating));

let obj = {};
for(let i=0;i<ratingData.length;i++){
  ratingData.forEach(value =>{
  obj[value.restaurant] = value.rating;
  
  });
}
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: You cannot have duplicated keys in an object.

Comment: Why do you iterate `ratingData.length * ratingData.length` times over `ratingData`? o.O

Comment: You want `Array.prototype.filter()`

Comment: removing the looop ratingData.length also gave same output. How to use Array.prototype.filter()

Comment: Your preferred search provider will surely help you to find a resource for that.

Answer (score 2):

You could make it with arrays of rating maybe? Multiple same keys name are impossible in objects

```js
ratingData = [
{restaurant: 'KFC', rating:5},
{restaurant: 'Burger King', rating:4},
{restaurant: 'KFC', rating:3},
{restaurant: 'Domino', rating:2},
{restaurant: 'Subway', rating:3},
{restaurant: 'Domino', rating:1},
{restaurant: 'Subway', rating:4},
{restaurant: 'Pizza Hut', rating:5}
]

let obj = {};
ratingData.forEach(({ restaurant, rating }) => {
  if (restaurant in obj) {
    obj[restaurant].push(rating);
  } else {
    obj[restaurant] = [rating];
  }
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Instead of doing push, can I add the sum?